# why installing mysql-server wants to remove sysvinit

Tags: mysql, debian, debian-squeeze

I want to install `mysql-server-5.5` in a new Debian Squeeze installation, but when I start to install it I get a warning that I don't see as being a requirement:

```
WARNING: The following essential packages will be removed.
This should NOT be done unless you know exactly what you are doing!
  sysvinit
```

It looks like the `upstart` package will be installed to replace `sysvinit`. Will proceeding with the install cause damage? Can you help me understand why `sysvinit` needs to be removed for `mysql-server` to be installed? Is there a way to install `mysql-server` without removing `sysvinit`?

Comment: The package mysql-server-5.5 is not available in the squeeze repos. Have you added repos for another version? Please post the contents of /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: Yes, Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Precise Pengolin. `deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main restricted universe multiverse` along with the `deb-src` entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu uses upstart by default, Debian does not, hence the problem with dependencies when you try to mix their packages. Mysql 5.5 is available in [debian wheezy](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/mysql-server-5.5), you may have better luck using those packages.